# R for loop with a function with upper/lowerbound / value range

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm struggling to use a for loop to apply a function that includes a value range "x:y" to every row of a data frame.

this is the function:

```
FPRfun <- function(A, B, C, P){
  N <- 2 * C - A - B - 1
  lbound <- C - B; ubound <- N
  FPR.summation <-
    ifelse(lbound <= ubound,
           sum(choose(N, lbound:ubound)), 0)
  FPR <- (1 - (FPR.summation / 2^(2 * C - A - B - 1))) * P
  return(FPR)
}
```

and this is my try of a for loop:

```
for(i in dataframe){
  FPR<-FPRfun(A, B, C, P)
  dataframe$FPR<-FPR
}
```

Unlike in functions wothout a value range, I get the warning

```
*In lbound:ubound : numerical expression has 15 elements: only the first used*
```

and the values are wrong.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: `lbound` is `C-B`, which probably gives a vector result like `c(1,2,3,4,5)` and when you do `c(1,2,3,4,5):10` you get a warning that only the first value will be used, giving the equivalent of `1:10`

Comment: @Ann - can you provide an example of your dataframe for us to work it out...seem like you might need to use `sapply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will get rid of the warning you are getting right now.

```
FPRfun <- function(A, B, C, P){
  N <- 2 * C - A - B - 1
  lbound <- C - B; ubound <- N
  FPR.summation <- mapply(function(i,j,k) ifelse(i<j,sum(choose( k,i:j)),0),lbound,ubound,N)
 FPR <- (1 - (FPR.summation / 2^(2 * C - A - B - 1))) * P
 return(FPR)
}
```

But the question still remains. What is the length of A,B,C and P? Is the length
same as that of the dataframe or not? If not then you will obtain a result with an error. It wont be able to add it to the data frame. At the same time on doing the for loop you will only receive the last values from your for loop since you are just replacing the same column every time. ie for i=1, you are storing your values in the dataframe$FPR, also when i=2. you are replacing this same column with the values obtained. Please check on that.

Comment: thank you that solved it! A, B, C, P all had the length 15 like the whole data frame.